# Submit a HTML form without redirection and showing a success message

Tags: javascript, php, forms, form-submit, ajaxform

I decided to switch from a WordPress website to a self-made with HTML, CSS and JS, aiming to improve performance. So far, relying on tutorials, I've managed to deal with almost every issue, but I just can't get the contact form work the way it worked in WP. So far it redirects me to another page that shows the success message, which is just ugly.

Basically, I want the submit button to do 3 things: 1. Not to redirect me to another page. 2. Reset the form. 3. Display a success message.

Read many similar questions here, but as I am completely unfamiliar with AJAX, finally decided to post this question. Here's my code:

Index.html:

```
     <div>
        <form method="post" action="form.php" name="myForm">
          <input name="name" placeholder="Nombre" required>
          <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" required>
          <textarea rows="10" name="message" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
          <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar Mensaje" class="boton-rojo">
        </form>
      </div>
```

and in form.php:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="De: $name \n Mensaje: $message";
$recipient = "contacto@mydomainname.cl";
$subject = "Mensaje desde el sitio web";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Tu consulta fue recibida";

?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you just need to combine both scripts into a single page (index.php), to "redirect" the form action to it like `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and to display initially only the form, or only the success message upon submit. of course you can use AJAX as well if you want to avoid page refresh.

Comment: sidenote: you should read up on header injection and then add validation on the `$email` var, so spammers cant use your script to spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Put an ID to your form**

```html
<form id='myForm'>
....
</form>
```

**Use jQuery (For easy code)**

```html
   ....
   <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

**Use $.ajax**

```js
$('#myForm').submit(function(e) {

   e.preventDefault(); // prevent from submitting form directly

   $.ajax({
     url: 'form.php',
     method: 'post',
     data: $("#myForm").serializeArray() // convert all form data to array (key:value)
   })
   .done(function(response){
     alert(response); // show the response
     $("#myForm").reset(); // reset the form
   })
   .fail(function(error){
     alert(error); // show the error.
   });

})
```

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly should I put the ajax? in the index.html, after the form?

Comment: The page you have the form

Comment: Did it just after the form, but nothing happens. Atom is not even color coding it, so I suppose something must be wrong with what I did.

Comment: Ok I got it, it was supposed to go into the javascript file.

Comment: Update: Loaded it into the server, everything works fine! but the form doesn't reset. What can be the issue?

Comment: Logged into the console, told me there was a type error `TypeError: $(...).reset is not a function`. Solved it just adding a classic `document.getElementById("myForm").reset();`

Comment: replace `document.getElementById("myForm")` with `$('#myForm')`. I updated my answer